# Using AnimeJS with FabricJS's objects

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs, anime.js

thanks for all your help in my previous post.
I have a question is it possible to use AnimeJS on FabricJS objects ? 
I mean, I have an AngularJS app with Canvas (FabricJS) and I can create object in this canvas. The FabricJS animations are not so powerfull instead of AnimeJS one, so I need to use it.

I already tried to interact with the object by getting them and using in "targets" param of AnimeJS. I can confirm that AnimeJS is working great in AngularJS app if my target is a dom type (like div), class or even id.

```
var bounce = anime({
            targets: object.get(),
            translateY: '50vh',
            duration: object.get().animation.duration * 1000,
            loop: true,
            direction: 'alternate',
            easing: 'easeInCubic',
            autoplay: true
        });
```

The object is correctly referenced in the bounce object, but nothing is animating. Do you have an idea ? Is it because of the target not correctly assigned ? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way, not using the animejs library. 
AnimeJS library is using DOM element, FabricJS elements are not DOM.
So,now I use GSAP library. Really easy to use too.

Comment: GSAP is a licensed tool

Answer (score 2):

you can use anime.js with fabric if you are operating on fabric object properties eg.

```
const [obj1] = canvas.getObjects();
anime({
    targets: [obj1],
    left: [-300, 300],
    easing: 'linear',
    update: function() {
        canvas.renderAll()
    }
});
```

Note that `left` is a fabric property. Whereas the `translateY` you were trying to use is a CSS property.

Ref: https://animejs.com/documentation/#JSobjProp

Comment: Nice, didn't notice I can do that using this point of view. Thanks for your answer